# Crawling a given URL w/ BeautifulSoup (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Halp!

I'm trying to write a web-crawler in python. The goal is to (eventually) loop through a list of domains, crawl all local-URLs within those domains, and dump all of the HTML content back to my host.

For now, I'm handing the script a single domain (http://www.scrapethissite.com). I've defined a queue, as well as sets for new/processed/local/foreign/broken-URLs. Based on the output, it looks like the script is reading in HTML of the page, grabbing the first local_URL ('https://scrapethissite.com/lessons/'), but failing to process that URL by adding it to the queue.

Ideally, the script would spit out each input URL's output into its own directory, preserving the DOM of the TLD. But I'd be happy just to get the queue working.

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import requests.exceptions 
from collections import deque
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlparse
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen 
import requests
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import lxml


#set targets
url = 'https://scrapethissite.com'
new_urls = deque(([url]))
processed_urls = set()
local_urls = set()
foreign_urls = set()
broken_urls = set()

#process urls until we exhaust queue
while len(new_urls):   

    url = new_urls.popleft()    
    processed_urls.add(url)
    print("processing %s..." % url)
    
    try:
        response = requests.get(url).text
        print(response)
        print(new_urls)

    except(requests.exceptions.MissingSchema, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.InvalidURL, requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema):    
        broken_urls.add(url)
        print(("this %s failed") % url)
        continue    
       

##get base URL to differentiate local and foreign addresses
    ###not working
print("differentiating addresses...")
parts = urlsplit(url)
base = "{0.netloc}".format(parts)
strip_base = base.replace("www.","")
base_url = "{0.scheme}://{0.netloc}".format(parts)
path = url[:url.rfind('/')+1] if '/' in parts.path else url



#initialize soup
print("initializing soup...")
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

#get links in HTML 
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    anchor = link.attrs["href"] if "href" in link.attrs else ''

#scrape page for links
print("scraping links...")
if anchor.startswith('/'):        
    local_link = base_url + anchor        
    local_urls.add(local_link)    
elif strip_base in anchor:        
    local_urls.add(anchor)    
elif not anchor.startswith('http'):        
    local_link = path + anchor        
    local_urls.add(local_link)    
else:        
    foreign_urls.add(anchor)
    print(forieng_urls)
    print(local_urls)
    
#to crawl local urls
#...and add them to sets
for i in local_urls:    
    if not i in new_urls and not i in processed_urls:        
        new_urls.append(i)
        
    
#to crawl all URLs
#for i in local_urls:
    #if not link in new_urls and not link in processed_urls:
       #new_urls.append(link)

print("new urls: %s" % new_urls)
print("processed urls: %s" % processed_urls)
print("broken urls: %s" % broken_urls)
```

And here's the output:

```
(base) $ crawler % python3 bsoup_crawl.py
processing https://scrapethissite.com...
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Scrape This Site | A public sandbox for learning web scraping</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/static/images/scraper-icon.png" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="A public sandbox for learning web scraping">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/styles.css">

    

  </head>

  <body>
    <nav id="site-nav">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li id="nav-homepage">
                            <a href="/" class="nav-link hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                <img src="/static/images/scraper-icon.png" id="nav-logo">
                                Scrape This Site
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="nav-sandbox">
                            <a href="/pages/" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-console hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>
                                Sandbox
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="nav-lessons">
                            <a href="/lessons/" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-education hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>
                                Lessons
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="nav-faq">
                            <a href="/faq/" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i>
                                FAQ
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li id="nav-login" class="pull-right">
                            <a href="/login/" class="nav-link">
                                Login
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var path = document.location.pathname;
            var tab = undefined;
            if (path === "/"){
                tab = document.querySelector("#nav-homepage");
            } else if (path.indexOf("/faq/") === 0){
                tab = document.querySelector("#nav-faq");
            } else if (path.indexOf("/lessons/") === 0){
                tab = document.querySelector("#nav-lessons");
            } else if (path.indexOf("/pages/") === 0) {
                tab = document.querySelector("#nav-sandbox");
            } else if (path.indexOf("/login/") === 0) {
                tab = document.querySelector("#nav-login");
            }
            tab.classList.add("active")
        </script>

    

    <div id="homepage">

        <section id="hero">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <img src="/static/images/scraper-icon.png" id="townhall-logo" />
                        <h1>
                            Scrape This Site
                        </h1>
                        <p class="lead">
                            The internet's best resource for learning <strong>web scraping</strong>.
                        </p>
                        <br><br><br>
                        <a href="/pages/" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" />Explore Sandbox</a>
                        <a href="/lessons/" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" />
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></i>
                            Begin Lessons &rarr;
                        </a>
                    </div><!--.col-->
                </div><!--.row-->
            </div><!--.container-->
        </section>

    </div>


    <section id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center text-muted">
                    Lessons and Videos &copy; Hartley Brody 2018
                </div><!--.col-->
            </div><!--.row-->
        </div><!--.container-->
    </section>
  </body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-Sk3nkD6mLTMOF0EOpNtsIry+s1CsaqQC1rVLTAy+0yc= sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pnotify/2.1.0/pnotify.core.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pnotify/2.1.0/pnotify.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- pnotify messages -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
    PNotify.prototype.options.styling = "bootstrap3";
    $(function(){
      
    });
    

    $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
  </script>

  <!-- golbal video controls -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("video").hover(function() {
        $(this).prop("controls", true);
    }, function() {
        $(this).prop("controls", false);
    });

    $("video").click(function() {
        if( this.paused){
            this.play();
        }
        else {
            this.pause();
        }
    });
    </script>

  <!-- insert google analytics here -->
  <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-41551755-8', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>

  <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
  <script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
  n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
  document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

  fbq('init', '764287443701341');
  fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
  <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=764287443701341&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
  /></noscript>
  <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->

  <!-- Google Code for Remarketing Tag -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 950945448;
    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    var google_remarketing_only = true;
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
    </script>
    <noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
    <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/950945448/?guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
  </noscript>

  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google AdWords: 950945448 -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-950945448"></script>
  <script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());

   gtag('config', 'AW-950945448');
  </script>

</html>
deque([])
differentiating addresses...
initializing soup...
scraping links...
new urls: deque(['https://scrapethissite.com/lessons/', <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="/lessons/"></a>])
processed urls: {'https://scrapethissite.com'}
broken urls: set()
```

Comment: So, what's going wrong? Unintended output? Errors?

Comment: It looks like the crawler sees the first local_url (https://scrapethissite.com/lessons/), adds it to the queue, but doesn't then process it and move on. It is supposed to process the queue, add that to the processed_url set, and then move on to the next URL. I think there is a problem with one of my loops but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hey it's Hartley -- operator of scrapethissite.com :)  The first thing that stands out to me  is that it looks like the bulk of your scraping logic is not contained inside your `while len(new_urls):  ` loop. You start with `new_urls` containing one URL, then you pop that one URL out of the queue, visit it, print the contents... and then exit the loop. Everything else happens outside the loop. In python, you need to make sure all of the subsequent code (`##get base URL to differentiate` and below) is indented to the same level as the rest of the code in your `while` loop. Hope that help!

Comment: Hello Hartley, thanks for the help and for running the site! When I try to indent the code following (`##get base URL to differentiate`), I get `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`. I get this error on the first line of indented code at the aforementioned section, whether I add a single or double tab to the line. Do I need to move everything up into the **while:, try:, and except:** sections accordingly?

Comment: Update: I've got the loop working properly, and my crawler successfully grabs a few links and processes them before breaking on one that it doesn't like - presumably a problem with either my URL parsing or error-handling logic? It's reading in the last URL as `new urls: deque([<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="/lessons/"></a>])`